# Referencing the top cell in a filtered column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a data table I'm using AutoFilter to filter results on.

I'm trying to figure out a way to use VBA to pull the top 5 cells from that filtered list and paste them onto a separate summary sheet but am trying to avoid having a Macro that will just go back and forth copying and pasting (flashing lights and all).

I've tried to get this done via formula but it always ends up returning duplicate values as the table gets filtered.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A19)-ROW(A1),,1)),ROW(A1:A19))))
```

Does anyone have a straight forward way to pull the top 5 visible cells from a filtered array and paste them onto another sheet?

EDIT: working with Excel 2016

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can use the new `FILTER`-Function plus `LARGE`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've heard about that function but my company only has Excel 2016 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(MyRange,SMALL(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(MyRange,1),ROW(MyRange)-MIN(ROW(MyRange)),)),ROW(MyRange)-MIN(ROW(MyRange))+1),ROWS(A$1:A1)))`

and copied down.

This will require committing as an *array formula* (i.e. with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`) for your version of Excel.

Note that *MyRange* should be set so as not to comprise the header row.

Comment: Jos, Thank you so much, that worked!!

I also figured out why this was giving me so much trouble to begin with... As I was dragging the formula down in my results area the search range was also being moved accordingly rather than just the last value in "...ROWS(A$1:A1)".

In any case, thanks so much again! Been banging my head against the wall all day with this one!